# Apollonius circles- three intersecting circles

Tags: euclidean-geometry, circles

The given problem is this: three circles intersecting each other. I have to construct a tangent circle for those three using a method of inversion. My profesor says there are 4 solutions. I understand the classical problem with three non-intersecting circles,but im having trouble figuring this one out. Im not asking for a full solution(if you have it great,send it please) but if someone could atleast give me pointers or something,that would be great.
Thank you in advance

Comment: What do you mean with “three circles intersecting each other”? Just that each one intersects the other two? Or that there's a point that belongs to the three circles?

Comment: Basically its like a venn diagram, as you said, every circle intersects the other two

Comment: Then your teacher is wrong; there may be $8$ solutions. I shall post an answer with a diagram.

Comment: Really? Well thank you very much. I am very grateful.

Comment: Done. I hope you enjoy it.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your teacher is wrong. See the image below. The black circles are the given circles and, as you can see, each one of them intersects the other two. And there are $8$ Apollonius circles (in red).

[image]

Comment: Wow, thank you very much, this helps a lot. Now i`m not sure why my profesor said 4 solutions. This will help me with the construction. Once again thank you.

Comment: Very interesting (+1)

Comment: Hello again,so i have another problem. I have figured out a way to construct the three smallest tangent circles for this case, but cannot find a proper way to do the other three(i am not counting the biggest one encompassing all other). Can you give an advice about that?

Comment: @EmilEterovic Don't expect help from me any time soon. I havn't thought about this for a long time.

Comment: Ok, thanks anyway, you sir, did much already. Have a good day.

Answer (score 0):

So in the attachment there is a picture of what i did in geogebra for the construction of the three bigger(the biggest one not included). Now this method obviously is not good. the yellow circles are my intersecting ones. i shrinked them for the radii of the smallest,then i found the images of them using the inversion method. after that i found their tangents(i picked the green one) and again using the inversion method, found its image. What part of this is wrong? Can you give me an advice?[image from geogebra](https://i.stack.imgur.com/MnTwE.png)